# Phantom js won't open any pages

Tags: phantomjs

I'm trying to make Phantom JS load a page, but no matter what, it responds with an "operation canceled   :(   I've tried various versions settings that ignore ssl and various websites. But neither works.

I can reach all sites with a normal browser and run PhantomJS locally from a fully updated mac osx

`./phantomjs --ignore-ssl-errors=true --ignore-ssl-errors=yes --ssl-protocol=tlsv1 ../../index.js http://askbar.dk`

yelds

```
= onNavigationRequested
destination_url: http://askbar.dk/
type (cause): Other
will navigate: true
from page's main frame: true
= onResourceRequested()
request: {
"headers": [
    {
        "name": "Accept",
        "value": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
    },
    {
        "name": "User-Agent",
        "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36"
    }
],
"id": 1,
"method": "GET",
"time": "2016-04-11T20:05:39.998Z",
"url": "http://askbar.dk/"
}
= onNavigationRequested
  destination_url: about:blank
  type (cause): Other
  will navigate: true
  from page's main frame: true 
  http://askbar.dk/: Operation canceled

phantomjs://code/index.js:60 in onResourceError
= onResourceReceived()
  id: 1, stage: "end", response: {"contentType":null,"headers":[],"id":1,"redirectURL":null,"stage":"end","status":null,"statusText":null,"time":"2016-04-11T20:05:39.999Z","url":"http://askbar.dk/"}
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. I've tried PhantomJS 1.9.8 and 2.1.1 and both open the page perfectly fine. What's index.js?

Comment: Yes... I suspect a local setting like firewall or something.. maybe

Comment: Curl works fine from the same terminal  :/